# Social login using cognito endpoint url

Tags: flutter

I want to integrate social login using cognition in my flutter app. I am using this https://.auth.us-east2.amazoncognito.com endpoint Url and then call Cognito I am getting a null response in social login. I am using the right endpoint url. Please tell me that should be an end point url. If I need to deploy endpoint url or it can be found in asw user pool. Please tell me about endpoint url and how can I get this endpoint url.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement amplify dependancy using

```
  amplify_flutter: ^0.1.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.1.0
  amplify_core: ^0.1.0
```

and with web UI

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter#amazon-cognito-user-pool-setup